# how to load a library dynamically?

Tags: r

Sorry for asking easy question. I am a R beginner. I tried to load a library run-time, 
e.g.

```
x<-"snow"; library(eval(x))
```

Result:

```
Error in library(eval(x)) : 'package' must be of length 1.
```

I would appreciate it if anyone gave me some solutions.

Comment: You already have the answer but in general it's a good idea to check the documentation for the functions you're asking about before posting your question - a lot of times you'll be able to find the answers yourself this way.  `?library`

Comment: This difficulty (making `R` treat a char string as the name of an object) pops up a lot. Some functions, like `library`, have internal code to do the translation.  Many don't, at which point tools like `do.call` come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `require` instead of `library`.

- `require` returns a logical indicating whether the package was successfully loaded, i.e. you can use it in constructs like

  ```
  if (require (x, character.only = TRUE))
      ...
  ```

  On contrast, `library` will by default stop with an error if the package is not available (you can change this behaviour by `logical.return = TRUE`, though).
- In case the package is loaded already, and this part of code is executed often, speed may matter: `require` is almost 20x faster than `library` on my laptop if the package is loaded already. If not, it calls `library`.

Answer (score 12):

Use `character.only=TRUE`.  See the help page for library, with `?library`.

```
> library(x, character.only=TRUE)
```